# Can a sub array be passed to another page as array with checkbox?

Tags: post, multidimensional-array, checkbox

I'm new to php so please pardon me if I'm asking something which is basic and asked before. I have googled for this for a few days now and esp. this forum where I found most of my previous answers but I can't find anything for this problem so I must ask. This is my first question.

```
// this array is coming from MySQL db as a result. It's a list of user's friends and it could contain dozens or hundreds of friends. Now he wants to put them in different groups.

$array = array(
       array("John", "Doe", "1"),
       array("Peter", "Citizen", "2")
       ...
      );


// a page is created with the result. Each record has a checkbox that the user can select.

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">

<?php

foreach($array as $item){
$nItem = $item;

?>

<input type="text" name="fname" value="<?php if(isset($nItem)){echo $nItem[0];} ?>" readonly="readonly" />
<input type="text" name="lname" value="<?php if(isset($nItem)){echo $nItem[1];} ?>" readonly="readonly" />
<input type="text" name="uid" value="<?php if(isset($nItem)){echo $nItem[2];} ?>" readonly="readonly" />
<input type="checkbox" name="val[]" value="<?php if(isset($nItem)){echo $nItem;} ?>" /> // I want to send this $nItem array as it is to the action page and read its keys and values there.
<br>

<?php
}
?>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<br />

<?php

// if I tick both checkboxes and submit I get the following:

if(isset($_POST['val'])){

$val = $_POST['val'];

echo var_dump($val), '<br />'; // array(2) { [0]=> string(5) "Array" [1]=> string(5) "Array" }

echo count($val), '<br />';    // 2

print_r($val);                 // Array ( [0] => Array [1] => Array )

echo("val is {$val[0]}");      // val is Array

foreach($val as $key => $value){
    echo "Key and Value are: ".$key." ".$value, '<br />'; // Key and Value are: 0 Array
}                                                         // Key and Value are: 1 Array

}

?>
```

It just returns a string "Array" instead of actual array that I can read the velues from. If I put individual values in checkbox value such as --

```
if(isset($nItem)){echo "".$nItem[0]." ".$nItem[1]." ".$nItem[2]."";}
```

-- then I get --

```
0 John Doe 1
```

-- but that's not what I want. I want the actual array on the action page that I can iterate through. I thought since it was already an array it wouldn't be difficult but I was wrong.

Could anyone please show me how to do it?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php foreach($array as $item): ?>
    <input type="text" name="fname" value="<?php echo $item[0]; ?>" readonly="readonly" />
    <input type="text" name="lname" value="<?php echo $item[1]; ?>" readonly="readonly" />
    <input type="text" name="uid" value="<?php echo $item[2]; ?>" readonly="readonly" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="val" value="<?php echo htmlentities(serialize($item)); ?>" />
    <br>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

After submitting, unserialize array $_POST['val'].
Depending on what you do with this array, this method is not very save to use with an eye on injections.

Instead of working with arrays containing all info, you'd better use id's for each record.
The checkbox named "val" has a value of the corresponding id then.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="val" value="<?php echo $item['id']; ?>" />
```

After submitting, query the record belonging to the id and use the returned array to work with.